# GUI framework for City Simulation Game for Python

Tags: open-source, python, gui, framework

## Software suggestion:

- I need a **GUI framework** which facilitates ***my requirements.***
- **City Simulation** means building a city from plain land. Or **City Building Game** which is same as **City Simulation!**

---

### Requirements:

**1. Free**
**2. Open-source**
**3. Easy to use**
**4. Compatible with Python**
**5. 3D icon support**

---

#### Thank you.

Comment: I think this is the question for stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy is free, open-source, easy to use, and compatible with Python. As for 3D icons, I recommend using software like Blender to render them as image files and then they could easily be used in Kivy. If you need something like animated 3D icons, you would need to use a different package to render them.

https://kivy.org/#home